# Spring security session creation

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-security

How can I initialize the Application at each creation of session 
As the problem that is facing me is 
When one user Log in to my app new session is created 
and when another user try to log in in the same time he see that the first user is logged in , I need to know how to initialize the App for the second user without any conflicts between two users 
My Class is

```
@Component
public class MyHttpSessionEventPublisher extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {

    @Autowired
    LoginBean loginBean;
   @Override
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      super.sessionCreated(event);
      event.getSession().getId();
    //  loginBean.setLoginDao(null);
      System.out.println("Session id is : "+ event.getSession().getId());
      System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> session created <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
   }

   @Override
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      //do something
      super.sessionDestroyed(event);

      System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> session destroyed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
   }

}
```

Any Help Please 
Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- This Listener for listening on creating new session -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>main.com.zc.attSys.security.beans.MyHttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name> <param-value>none</param-value> 
        </context-param> -->

    <!-- This Part for Spring security Configurations -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- This Part for removing session id from URl 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>URLSessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>main.com.zc.attSys.security.beans.URLSessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>URLSessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

    </filter-mapping>
-->


    <context-param>

        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>
              /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml

        </param-value>

    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>

    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext-Security.xml is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/jdbc.properties" />
    <!-- For Spring auto wiring -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="main.com.zc.attSys" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/> --> 

        <form-login username-parameter="Mail"  password-parameter="Password" 
         login-page="/pages/courseFeedBack/ask/login.xhtml"  
        login-processing-url="/home.xhtml"
         always-use-default-target="true"
         authentication-failure-url="/pages/courseFeedBack/ask/login.xhtml"
        />

    </http>

    <!-- <authentication-manager> <authentication-provider> <user-service> <user 
        name="joseph" password="bagnes" authorities="Admin, User"/> <user name="bernabe" 
        password="jose" authorities="User"/> </user-service> </authentication-provider> 
        </authentication-manager> -->

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></beans:property>

    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: If you log in in the same browser, you will see the first login. That's normal and expected. Make sure you are using a different browser.

Comment: Yes I'm using different browsers

Comment: and what is the use case, logging in with two different users at the same time, or logging in twice in different browsers with the same user? also what error message or error behaviour are you getting when trying to login in, can you post the logs

Comment: use case is a normal site behavior like Facebook different users cand log in with their accounts in the same time , , my developed site see that for example if you logged before me and I tried to log in I see that someone is logged in  my app allows that .. !
The memory isn't cleaned or the session isn't created for new access to the app I dont know ! :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow multiple users to login with the same username at the same time, we can use the concurrency control features of the http element, see [in the docs page 15](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.pdf):

```
<http>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions=2 />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Beware of a common pitfall by adding this to web.xml, otherwise concurrent logins won't work:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

See also this [FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-session-listener-missing) for related common problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response
But the problem is 
two different users isn't Allowed , 
when the second user try to log in he see that already someone else is logged in 
And about the second point 
I Put
<listener>
    <listener-class>main.com.zc.attSys.security.beans.MyHttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
 </listener>
There are the same right ?

Comment: OR what Should I do to Initialize The Application for the new user ?

Comment: this should work out of the box with spring security, can you post your web.xml and your spring-security configuration? you are using spring security right, or are you manually managing the session?

Comment: I edited the post and attached web.xml , Spring security files 
yes I used spring security , but I'm very newbie at spring security my first use for it